# Is there any way to overwrite FastAPI logout function?

Tags: cookies, oauth, jwt, fastapi

I am writing an applicaion using FastAPI and have run into a problem with accessing HTMLResponse page with required authentication where I have had to start using cookies to handle that. But after implementing this I started having even more problems: built in logout function which appears after logging in doesnt remove my token from cookies and all auth-required handles can be accesed after logging out. I have spent quite some time to find workaround but nothing seems to work. I want to overwrite "logout" function to make it remove tokens from cookies. Is there any way to do this?
Here is my login and logout handlers code:

```py
@auth_router.post("/login/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    response: Response,
    form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
) -> Dict[str, str]:
    user = await authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={
            "sub": user.email,
            "other_custom_data": [
                "We`ll use that later",
            ],
        },
        expires_delta=access_token_expires,
    )
    response.set_cookie(
        key=settings.COOKIE_NAME, value=f"Bearer {access_token}", httponly=True
    )
    return {settings.COOKIE_NAME: access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}


@auth_router.post("/logout")
async def logout():
    response = RedirectResponse(url="/docs")
    response.delete_cookie(settings.COOKIE_NAME)
    return response
```

With this logout handler cookies get removed but I want the same functionality to be in te logout provided with this icon in FastAPIs Swagger docs
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Hmf.png)

Comment: There is no such thing as a built-in logout function in FastAPI. Are you using a specific authentication library? In that case, which one?

Comment: I was using jose for working with web-tokens and OAuth2PasswordBearer from fastapi.security for authentication.

Comment: You'll have to actually include the code you're using for anybody to say what might be the problem - you might not be sending a request to the user to delete the cookie for example (which is usually done by sending a cookie with the name and instant expiry time - usually set to 1970 or something similar).